# Having a syntax error when creating a database in row 1 column 14

Tags: java, sql

```java
public static void buildOrderTable(Connection conn)
{
    try
    {
     // Get a Statement object.
     Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
     
        // Create the table.
        stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE Order (" +
                       "OrderNo DOUBLE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, " +
                  "CustomerName CHAR(25), " +
                  "Flavor CHAR(10), " +
                  "Topping CHAR(10), " +                  
                  "QuantityIceCream DOUBLE, " +    
                  "BreadType CHAR(10), " +
                  "SandwichType CHAR(10), " +
                  "QuantitySandwich CHAR(10), " +
                  "Discount DOUBLE, " +
                  "Subtotal DOUBLE, " +
                  "Tax DOUBLE, " +
                  "Total DOUBLE " +
                  ")");
    }
    catch (SQLException ex)
  {
     System.out.println("ERROR: " + ex.getMessage());
  }
}
```

I keep getting:
ERROR: Syntax error: Encountered "Order" at line 1, column 14.

even when I've deleted or added columns it is still at column 14

I've deleted each column 1 at a time, but that didn't resolve the issue.

I'm also confused why there are even 14 columns as I only have 12 items.

Comment: Order is an sql keyword. "Column 14" refers to the character in line 1 where the error was encountered, not the columns of your table. Easiest fix is to call your table something different.

Comment: Thank you, I've renamed all "Order"'s to "Sales". It works now

Answer (score 0):

This error

```
ERROR: Syntax error: Encountered "Order" at line 1, column 14.
```

is nothing to do with the columns in your table. Line 1 column 14 is the beginning of the word "Order" in the line "CREATE TABLE Order".

It's an error because Order is an SQL keyword. I suggest you call your table something else.

Alternatively you could quote the table name to indicate that it is an identifier. In MySQL that would be

```
CREATE TABLE `Order`
```

But it depends what kind of database you're using.